# sequence consisting of finite number of distinct values.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a question from my previous year analysis exam .The question says :

> Can we construct a sequence which converges but never attains its limits,such that its terms consist of a finite number of distinct values ?
>
> If yes,give an example.If not explain ..

I cannot frame any kind of example.Any hint would be of great help..

Answer (score 1):

Limits are normally practicized in topologies where the singletons, hence the finite sets are closed. This to ensure their uniqueness.

If $S$ is the set of the distinct values of a convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ - i.e. $S=\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ - then the limit must belong to the closure of $S$. If $S$ is finite then it is closed, hence coincides with its closure. Consequently the limit must belong to $S$.

Comment: The sequence to be constructed must be infinite.Then how with finite terms should we ensure the convergence of sequence..

Comment: please help If you have any idea..

Comment: $a_n=a$ for each $n\geq n_0$. What is in your view an infinite sequence?

Comment: but then isn't the limit attained ,which should not be attained according to the question..

Comment: As I meant to say in my answer: if $\{a_n|n\in\mathbb N\}$ is finite then $(a_n)$ **cannot** be a converging sequence that never attains the value of the limit.

Comment: what I think of an infinite sequence is that we can find a term in the sequence ${a_n}$ given any $n>n_o$ for every $n_o \in \mathbb N$.I don't know if i'm correct.

Comment: I wan't the generating set of sequence to be finite, not the sequence..

Comment: If $a_n$ is defined for each $n\in\mathbb N$ (you call it an infinite sequence, I call it just a sequence) and $\{a_n|n\in\mathbb N\}$ (generating set) is finite then the sequence $(a_n)$ converges if and only if some $n_0$ exists with $n\geq n_0\rightarrow a_n=a_{n_0}$. That is the essence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, take a sequence $a_n$ whose terms have either the value $b$ or $c$.
Neither of both can be the limit, so the limit must be some number $d$ with
$d \neq b,c$. Now think about the distance of an arbitrary term in the sequence $a_n$ to its supposed limit $d$.

You should get it from here ;-).

Comment: But I can't understand how to manage the distance such that it converges,i.e. how to adjust no. of a's and b's to to converge to d.Please help..

Comment: Who said that it converges? I try to help you to get some understanding of the problem, not the ready-made solution. This would not help you in the long run.

Comment: Ok I'll try and then ask you whether it's correct..

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such sequence of real numbers.

Suppose $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow \{a_1,\dots,a_m\}\subset \mathbb R$ and that $x_n=f(n)$. If $x_n$ converges to $x$ then given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that 
$|x-x_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Select $\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}\min\{|a_i-a_j|:1\leq i<j\leq m \}$. Then $|x-x_k|<\epsilon \Rightarrow x_k=x_n$, which is easy to prove.